# ActionBarCompat Not Working

Tags: android, android-appcompat

**Im use Intellij Idea Community Edition v13**
and i cant use  
because; i show error: @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light **cannot resolve**

I add support v7 library; **File> Project Structure > Libraries**;
have 2 library **[android-support-v4 and android-support-v7-appcompat**]

**AndroidManifest.xml;**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion     ="7"/>
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion  ="17"/>
...
..
<activity
     android:name    =".MyApp"
     android:label   ="@string/AppName">
     <intent-filter>
          <action     android:name    ="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
          <category   android:name    ="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

-

**MyApp.class;**

```
...
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
...
public class Sozler extends ActionBarActivity{
...
```

-

**In my > MyApp class;**

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
          actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
          actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

***Running successfully Android 3.0+ Device***, but when i working Android 2.3 Device;

**> I see exception;**

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.createDelegate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:54)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:96)
            at com.kibar.App.MyApp.onCreate(MyApp.java:16)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
```

Comment: what is line 16 `MyApp.java`?

Comment: super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: post the code `Sozler.java`.

Comment: at com.kibar.App.MyApp.onCreate(MyApp.java:16); edit this, my code working normally Device 3.0+, but i running my app 2.3 Device not working..

Line 16 > super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: I don't think you have referenced appcompat properly cross check by referencing https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: Using Android Studio

Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Repository using the SDK Manager.
Open the build.gradle file for your application.
Add the support library feature project identifier to the dependencies section. For example, to include the appcompat project add compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+" to the dependencies section, as shown in the following example:
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
}
but i dont have build.gradle. Because i dont use AndroidStudio and Eclipse im use Intellij Idea so..

Comment: sorry i haven't used intellid ide but have heard its similaar to studio. i can't comment on that good luck

Comment: ok thank you how i can resolve this problem i dont know :)